# how to add an light black overlay to an image with text over it?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Following is my HTML code:

```
<div id="fh5co-blog-section">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="seller">
      <img src="assets/img/contact.jpg" class="img-responsive">
    </div>
    <h1 class="text-center">Contact Us</h1>
    <p>Get in touch with us for any additional queries, suggestions or feedback regarding any product.</a></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

What i am trying to achieve is that, i want to add an overlay to the image that i have linked, also i want the text displayed over the overlay thing. But somehow i am not able to achieve it my codes are jumbling everytime. I also searched various sites and answers on stackoverflow, but i wan't able to find the exact solution. Can anyone help me with this thing. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

For your overlay, you can insert it inside a div(this div must have position:relative) and set their css:
 `position: absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0; background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);`. After that put your image and text inside that div. 
My example:http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrmQgo